# Alternative proof that the continuous image of a connected set is connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, continuity, connectedness

I have written a proof of the proposition (that the continuous image of a connected set is connected) slightly different from the ones on here so far (of which I am aware there are many). Is the following correct?

I have a continuous function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces such that $X$ is connected. I want to show that $f(X)$ is connected as a metric space, with the metric induced by $Y$.

Suppose, for a contradiction, that $f(X)$ is not connected. That is, there exists open sets $A,B$ such that $f(X)=A\cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Note that $A,B\subseteq Y$, and so, by the continuity of $f:X \rightarrow Y$, $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are both open in $X$. Additionally, $f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)= \emptyset$ (since, otherwise, $\exists x^*$ such that $x^*\in f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$ and so $f(x^*)\in A \cap B$, contradicting the assumed disjointedness of $A$ and $B$). Finally, we show that $X=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$.

$w\in f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B) \iff f(w) \in A \cup B = X \iff w\in X$.

So $X=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$, and is not connected. A contradiction.

Comment: This is correct, and never uses the fact that either $X$ or $Y$ is a metric space, so you've actually proved the proposition for topological spaces in general.

Comment: This looks like the “standard proof” to me.

Comment: Any reason you always use $:=$? The meaning I know for that is "is defined to equal", but none of those are definitions.

Comment: A minor point: you seem to be misusing $:=$.  That's usually used to introduce a definition; in contrast, if you're merely asserting equality of two preexisting objects, which is the case everywhere here, then you should use plain $=$.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are open sets in $f(X),$ not $Y.$ You will need a little more care.

Comment: @RobertShore No, it is not correct. $A\cup B=f(X)$ means we are talking about open sets in $f(X),$ not in $Y.$

Comment: I agree with @ThomasAndrews. For example, if $X$ consisted of two points and $f$ is injective and $Y=\Bbb R$, then there certainly aren't sets $A,B$ that are open in $Y$ such that $f(X)=A\cup B$.

Comment: Essentially, you need to know that if $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, then $f_0:X\to f(X)$ defined to be equal to $f$ is continuous. I guess in metric spaces, that's a little more obvious than in a general topology (where it is not much harder.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But $A \cup B = f(X) \subseteq Y$ (and so $A$, $B$ $\subseteq$ $Y$), right?

Comment: Definitely, $A,B\subseteq Y,$ but there is no reason to think $A,B$ are open in $Y.$ Indeed, $X=\mathbb R,Y=\mathbb R^2,$ and $f:x\mapsto (x,0),$ then no non-empty subset of $f(X)$ is open in $Y.$

Answer (score 1):

This is fine. I'll just make one small comment that it's totally unnecessary to phrase this as a proof by contradiction. This is a proof by [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive): you've shown that if $f(X)$ is not connected then $X$ is not connected.